# Unable to read excel sheet using ExcelReader in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using IExcelDataReader to reader to read a excel sheet using following code:

```
private static IExcelDataReader FetchDataReaderForExcel(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    IExcelDataReader dataReader = null;

    if (null != file)
    {
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        switch (fileExtension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                dataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                dataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file.InputStream);
                break;
            default:
                dataReader = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    return dataReader;
}
```

When i am reading the excel sheet using this method sometime i am not able to read the data correctly. Sometime it is not able to read column other time it is not able to read the entire data. I need to format each column to normal text and then upload again, it works then. Excel contains data contains integer, string, datetime, hyperlink. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem or alternative for this? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using oledb and it works perfect for me. Here is my example:

```
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\""))
    {
        //
        string listName = "Sheet1";
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter odb = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + listName + "$]", con);
            odb.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            foreach (DataRow myrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                Object[] cells = myrow.ItemArray;
                if (cells[0].ToString().Length > 0 || cells[1].ToString().Length > 0 || cells[2].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    /*
                    cells[0]
                    cells[1]
                    cells[2]
                    are getting values
                    */

                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

OLEDB.12.0 works with both .xls and .xlsx

Comment: Can i upload Excel file since our is a website and user need upload there excel sheet will this work there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are Uploading the file ,and the file has Many sheets in it and you want to read all the sheets you can follow this method....first write the Code for FileUPload and save the uploaded file in a path....using that path you can read the files

```
    /// <summary>

    /// This method retrieves the excel sheet names from 

    /// an excel workbook & reads the excel file


    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="excelFile">The excel file.</param>

    /// <returns></returns>
    #region GetsAllTheSheetNames of An Excel File
    public static string[] ExcelSheetNames(String excelFile)
    {
        DataTable dt;
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes'";

        using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            objConn.Open();
            dt =
            objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if (dt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            string[] res = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
            {
                string name = dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                if (name[0] == '\'')
                {
                    //numeric sheetnames get single quotes around
                    //remove them here
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^'\d\w+\$'$"))
                    {
                        name = name.Substring(1, name.Length - 2);
                    }
                }
                res[i] = name;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    #endregion
//You can read files and store the data in a dataset use them 
       public  static DataTable GetWorksheet(string excelFile,string worksheetName)
    {
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes'";  
        OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + worksheetName + "$]", con);

        con.Open();
        System.Data.DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);
        con.Close();

        return excelDataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

Else U can use this method to read the excel file

Just Add the reference
click on the "AddReference" on solution explorer ,click on com tab and Add this reference
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

```
    And add this namespace in your code behind
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
    using System.IO;
    using System.Data; 


     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Path = @"C:\samples\SEP DUMPS.xls";
        // initialize the Excel Application class
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();           
        //Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
        Excel.Range ShtRange;
        // create the workbook object by opening  the excel file.
        Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(Path,0,true,5,"","",true,Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,"\t",false,false, 0,true,1,0);
        // Get The Active Worksheet Using Sheet Name Or Active Sheet
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.ActiveSheet;
        int index = 1;
        // that is which cell in the excel you are interesting to read.
        object rowIndex = 1;
        object colIndex1 = 1;
        object colIndex2 = 5;
        object colIndex3 = 4;
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            while (((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex1]).Value2 != null)
            {
                rowIndex =index;
                string firstName = Convert.ToString( ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex1]).Value2);
                string lastName = Convert.ToString(((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex2]).Value2);
                string Name = Convert.ToString(((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex3]).Value2);
                string line = firstName + "," + lastName + "," + Name;
                sb.Append(line); sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine(" {0},{1},{2} ", firstName, lastName,Name);
                index++;
            }

           Writetofile(sb.ToString());

            ShtRange = workSheet.UsedRange;
            Object[,] s = ShtRange.Value;            


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            app.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
```

Hope this helps you..........If u have any doubts Ask me...